# Integrating wxWidgets into Existing XCode Project

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

There are many tutorials about setting up a **new** XCode project for use with wxWidgets, but I need to integrate it with a large **existing** XCode C++ project.

The wxWidgets setup process is unclear to me. I built wxWidgets in XCode with the included wxcocoa.xcodeproj file. But when I include all the header files and the libwx_osx_cocoa.dylib library to my existing XCode project, I get all these errors within the wxWidgets header files like `Use of undeclared identifier 'wxApp'` and `No matching constructor for initialization of 'wxEvent'` as if it's missing files, but I've included all the header files and compiled library. I tried building wxWidgets in the terminal and get the same errors. I tried `make install` to actually install wxWidgets on my system. I tried running this command `wx-config --cxxflags --libs all` in the terminal. I tried adding `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs all` to the compiler and linker flags in my XCode project. None of these had any effect.

The irony is that I'm trying to use wxWidgets library to make the GUI process easier, but instead I've spent two days pulling my hair out trying to get my C++ XCode project to compile. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** The problem seems to be XCode. I've downloaded the wxWidgets Hello World sample program at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html). I can build this program without issue in the terminal, but when I put it into a new XCode project, it won't build. How can I get XCode to build this simple program?

cx-config output:
[image: cx-config output]

XCode project settings:
[image: Linked Libraries]

[image: C++ Flags]

[image: Header Search Paths]

**EDIT 2:** I exported the Build Log out of XCode and saw that the actual build command uses clang. When I successfully compile Hello World in the terminal, I use clang++. When I try the same command with clang, it doesn't work. Perhaps this is the issue, since clang only links C libraries and the errors XCode is giving me relate to not being able to find standard C++ functions.

**EDIT 3:** Wow I hate XCode. I got my Hello World program to compile by accident. The solution was putting the wxWidgets compiler flags in the **Targets** Build Settings, whereas before, I had it in the **Project** Build Settings. I assumed the Targets would inherit the Project settings, but I guess not! [image: Compiler Flags]

**EDIT 4:** I got my complicated XCode project to compile with the wxWidgets libraries by taking all the search paths & flags and moving them from the Project Build Settings to the Targets Build Settings. What a nightmare! Glad it's over

Comment: what OSX version? XCode version? wxWidgets version? How did you create the project - what options did you selected?

Comment: Running macOS Monterey 12.6 on a Quad-Core Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro, XCode 14.1, wxWidgets-3.2.1. I'm going to update the OS right now to see if that changes anything.

I didn't create the XCode project—another team did.

Comment: Now running macOS 12.6.1

Answer (score 1):

@WaddleDee72

,
I suggest doing following:

1. Delete wxWidgets directory.
2. Unpack wxWidgets into i.e. ~/wxWidgets.
3. Open Terminal.
4. In the Terminal

4a. cd ~/wxWidgets

4b. mkdir buildOSX

4c. cd buildOSX

4d. ../configure --enable-debug

4e. make -j5

After successful build

5. wx-config --cxxflags
6. wx-config --libs

Use the output of 2 commands above and put the values where they belong in XCode project.

If you get any issues - let us know.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried this, but now I have new errors, specifically `buffer.h:599:9 Use of undeclared identifier 'memcpy'` (so I guess it can't find standard C++ libraries for the wxWidgets files?) and `defs.h:62:13 "No Target! You should use wx-config program for compilation flags!"`, which is frustrating because I specifically put all the output from the wx-config commands into the XCode project build settings.

Comment: I can successfully compile a wxWidgets Hello World program from the terminal with the flags, so the problem is either the XCode configuration (most likely) or some conflict with the existing C++ files of my project (less likely)

Comment: @WaddleDee72, for the test - can you create a brand new XCode project, add the values as you did, use the code from the minimal sample and build it?

Comment: About new errors - can you give a full error stack? And what standard you are using for building the library and your code?

Comment: Finally got it. The cx-config output needed to go in the Target Build Settings in XCode, not the Project Build Settings. Thank you for all your help!